# Construct $\mathbb{Z}$-invariant measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{Z}$ with $\mu(A) = 1$ for given $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

It is well-known that any finitely generated abelian group $G$ is supramenable which means that given any subset $A \subseteq G$ there exists a $G$-invariant finitely additive measure $\mathcal{P}(G) \to [0,\infty]$ such that $\mu(A) = 1$.

The only proof of this that I know is showing that any finitely generated group with sub-exponential growth is supramenable because sub-exponential growth prevents the existence of paradoxical decompositions and then appealing to Tarski's Theorem which states the existence of a measure with the desired properties. It is easy to see that finitely generated abelian groups have sub-exponential growth.

This proof is not constructive (it requires the Axiom of Choice) and so I was wondering if it is possible to construct more or less explicitly the required measures at least in the case of $G = \mathbb{Z}$.

Of course, if $A \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ is finite, then we can take $\mu(X) = \frac{|X|}{|A|}$. Or if $\nu$ is an invariant finitely additive measure for which $\nu(\mathbb{Z}) = 1$ (for example $ \nu(X) = \lim \frac{|X \cap [-n,n]|}{2n}$, but (as tkf commented) even this requires ultralimits to work), then if $\nu(A)$ is positive, we can rescale and take $\mu(X) = \frac{\nu(X)}{\nu(A)}$. But there are many subsets of $\mathbb{Z}$ which will statisfy neither of these conditions.

Comment: The limit you used to define $\nu$ does not exist for all subsets $X$.  For example if $X$ consists of integers $n$ such that $\lfloor\log_2(n)\rfloor$ is even, then the sequence oscillates between $\frac13$ and $\frac23$.  Instead it is usual to take the ultralimit here, with respect to a non-principle ultrafilter.  Of course that takes you right back to the axiom of choice.